# How change encoding in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, encoding

I want change encoding `UTF-8` from `UTF-16` for display `Unicode`.

How change encoding in android studio ?

I'm search in internet but The result did not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the bottom-right part of your Android Studio window:

[image: Bottom-right part of an Android Studio window]

Just click the appropriate dropdown (in this case, one that shows my current encoding: `UTF-8`) and you'll be greeted with a handful of other encoding options.