# Android Studio Showing Code Of All File In wrong Encoding

Tags: android-studio

**Gradle File**

?PNG

IHDR         ??a   ?IDATx?c`??????g?Di???P?r?e??5????s?C?y???c??\???`???}??X?x?a????b??a ?QMw??J?B6???k
?p
???P???*?HqB?8)  Q??????    IEND?B`?

**Manifest file**

�PNG

IHDR   0   3   і�)  �IDATx��YMOQ��Y�V����4���XJ��   �`���)���X *�EQ��P��Ъ|مδH��xo�����#�MΪw�Ι�������F7��$�� O  @P�.�8 � �C�>'��<  ��/��i��N��,��_�G��v�ؼ�I�T�S���X�,�Ԃ��������E��]����2�=Q��<�ܳ��h��[Q��k>~�$6_I���f���3��NX��v���#�[w�i!���E���H�o�U�%T!O�&?G���K���l&�"�HJ�b�ˆ����   �������ƥ/_��SV���,��_������%���.�F�ߥ����n'y8~e��!#�W5��R6����H�%?BW+'�V��861��=h��=���e��D r��"`�lR��<N�������Z31��g�Y�<9�Z�l�a�� �j��I�`.>��������Uji(!5zre ��P�"���$Ԉ!/�.%3rVj��O=N����B�hZ��%ֻj\G�,�ƾ \4�    �cA��C��O��Y��%��[�ht��"̒o�tC���,����+�T@MI@k�/.-;�����/��[_��Rv�$~�^�������֖�:e���N��u%�rV:�I;e#C.D����!�F��"oVr!���5�F����f90n^��C<�q��Z^;�i�9�:�C�`��k�6�:��،9��T6I5U�m�M�d�I=g���WyYx��9�6�"�c1FWV���F+����Q(j5k�7�\���7�
��zel��al��ܸYwn��\vY���m1y�f�6wy�s��!?��Fq���%;�^p��1�]1��xk����t��F\�ݘk�q�ݍnt����N����T    IEND�B`�
\

**xml Or java file all are converted like this **

```
{
"logs": [
    {
        "outputFile": "E:\\Husher\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-gl\\values-gl.xml",
        "map": [
            {
                "source": "C:\\Users\\BackB0i\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-1\\files-1.1\\places-1.1.0.aar\\e54a7510fa5f4dceb58db78ef6ff578d\\res\\values-gl\\values.xml",
                "from": {
                    "startLines": "4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11",
                    "startColumns": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                    "startOffsets": "184,254,320,422,485,532,606,703",
                    "endColumns": "69,65,101,62,46,73,96,55",
                    "endOffsets": "253,319,421,484,531,605,702,758"
                },
                "to": {
                    "startLines": "49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56",
                    "startColumns": "4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4",
                    "startOffsets": "58
```

**All Files are converted like this, But New project that i create are not effected**

Comment: Tried to change the [encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714358/how-change-encoding-in-android-studio)?

Comment: Looks heavily like each of those files have been replaced with PNG images.

Comment: How can I change it ? Their is option menu dialog "try another encoding  " i tried to select other but non of them worked . Files are still same

Comment: UTF 8 is selected by default but i dont know if error is due to encoding or their is something else